# Why's an error being throw when trying to use MouseEvent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, debugging

Anyone know what could be the issue here?  It's giving me an error that says:

`Unexpected token, expected ","`, it's pointing to the `event:` part but not sure what I'm supposed to do?  I've tried the obvious `event, ...` but that still didn't work

```
    const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
    const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

    const handleOpenNavMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
    };
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: post the full component

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I don't need to post the entire component as it's a big file.  I've edited my original post to show the main parts.

Comment: have duplicate `handleOpenNavMenu` methods

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka sorry that was a mistake, I've edited again

Comment: any html changes?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka no HTML changes were made.  the error is pointing to `event: ...`

Comment: looks good for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-pfgj8t?file=App.tsx,index.tsx